# Finding a summation involving gcd

Tags: number-theory, summation, totient-function, gcd-and-lcm

I am trying to evaluate the following sum:
$$b\sum_{i=a}^b\frac{i}{\gcd(i,b)}$$

I have solved the problem if $a=1$ but I am clueless for the case when $a$ is not $1$. For $a=1$, I used the fact that $\gcd(i, b)=\gcd(b-i, b)$ but this doesn't help for the above sum.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think this sum will have nice evaluation?

Comment: @Wojowu: Because the case $a=1$ has a nice closed form in terms of euler totient function. I need to implement this sum using a programming language. I am looking for ways to implement it in complexity better than $O(b)$.

Comment: @PranavArora what is the closed formula in the case $a=1$?

Comment: @PITTALUGA I think it was $\dfrac{\left(\sum_{d|b} d\phi(d)\right)+1}{2}$

Comment: @PranavArora Are you sure it's correct? Try with $b=p$ prime number

Comment: @PITTALUGA Oops, multiply that formula with $b$.

Comment: @PranavArora Just trying: what if you split the sum as $\sum_{i=1}^b \frac{i}{\gcd(i,b)}= \sum_{i=1}^b \frac{i}{\gcd(i,b)}-\sum_{i=1}^{a-1} \frac{i}{\gcd(i,b)}$? Is the last sum too bad to deal with?

Comment: @PITTALUGA I have already tried that but couldn't reach to anything simpler.